# Retrieve documentclass option as text string?

Tags: documentclass-writing

I am sure this is well-known among TeX gurus, but I could not easily find it. MWE (pseudo-code):

```
\documentclass[bunch,of,options]{anyclass}
\newcommand\theOptionString{} % What to put there? That is the question!
\begin{document}
\theOptionString % Desired print: bunch,of,options
\end{document}
```

No doubt the option string (unprocessed) is stored in a register somewhere, and can be retreived if the user knows the name of that register. Presumably needs `\makeatletter` and `makeatother` to get it. OK to use LuaTeX, if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not in a register just a normal macro, `\@classoptionslist`

Comment: this is mildly processed, it is expanded and white space removed

Comment: Great! Tested, works. Mildly processed OK (would have done it myself). `@classoptionslist` has to be used in the preamble, such as by `\makeatletter \let\theOptionString\@classoptions \makeatother` then `\theOptionString` can be used in the document body.

Comment: You can also patch `\@fileswith@pti@ns` if you want access prior to the processing.

Comment: @RobtA yes well in 1993 we need to free up the bytes used to store those characters to leave room for processing the document so quite a few things get undefined at begin document.  Probably now you don't appreciate having a few hundred bytes saved, but still:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have been saving bytes for more than two decades. Just last month, I took all the bytes I've saved and brought them to the recycling center, for cash. Now, with another 80 cents, I can buy myself a cup of coffee. :-)